# Road crankset with 29er mtb frame

Tags: road-bike, tire, off-road, 29er, compact-crankset

I wonder if anyone knows of a 29er frame that has clearance for at least 2.5 tires that will take a compact (50/34) road crankset? Preferably steel.

Comment: Just asking, but why would you put a road crankset on MTB? Are gear gaps too big with 1x?

Comment: Thinking of building a monster cross, I do ride quite a lot on tarmac and groomed gravel paths, so going is pretty fast. There are some pretty mad hills around here too. I just won't be able to find the right combo of on road speed and ability to climb with a 1x

Comment: Did you consider a gravel bike like 3T Exploro with 27.5" wheels and 2.1" tires? Sure, that's a bit less than 2.5", but big chainrings would fit for sure. Unless you require 10cm+ of front suspension, of course.

Comment: Another option is to get 5-arm road spider for direct mount crankset (SRAM or RaceFace). Big chainring clearance might still be an issue, but should it really be 50t? With 2.5" 29 tires 45/46t are the equivalent of 50t with 25mm tire. Also, the chainline might be off.

Comment: @Klaster_1 I like your second comment, thanks.  Just to clarify I ride 700x40c gravel tyres atm, not 28 lol. The tyres don't need to be 2.5, just nice to have the clearance if I wanted to go up.

Comment: 2.5" tires pretty much preclude road gearing. The trails you say you are riding do not require 2.5: tires, 30-42mm will be fine.

Comment: Sram 12 speed Eagle has a 10-50 cassette, giving same gear range 50-34 with a 11-36 cassette.   50/10 on 2.5" 29er is a big gear, can you honestly and practically make use of (aero effects mean pedaling at that speed is wasteful, better to tuck in and conserve energy for the uphill.)

Comment: @mattnz thanks for your comment. At the mo I run 50 34 front and 11 40 back for the bigger hills and fully loaded touring. I do run out of power (I know I should train more) on some hills offroad and I spin out on road decents. I currently run 700x40c tyres with some grip, but I'd like more for mud and those unconquered hills lol

Comment: And by the way, I ride drop bars and prefer to keep it that way 

Comment: 50-11 at 90 rpm on a 29er is about 35 mph.  If your goal is to get somewhere, you'd do much better just getting into an aerodynamic tuck and not pedaling.  Seriously.  You will go **faster** down a hill like that in the most aerodynamic position you can get than you would if you got into a less aerodynamic position and pedal. Because down hills like that, you're probably getting something about 2,000W of power from gravity. At those speeds, "2000W and aero" is faster than "2300W and non-aero". If you're on a training ride and need to keep pedaling for that reason, don't ride hills like that.

Comment: @Andrew Henle Do you mean like this..https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Iz7ZMALaCY

Comment: @mattnz Pretty much, although that was on a fixie, so a rider's inability to pedal fast enough might also slow that type of bike down (although the guys in that video probably didn't have *that* problem...).  Interestingly, down really steep hills, you can get get **more** power from gravity alone when you get aero than you would get from gravity plus pedaling when not as aero, if the hill is steep enough and the drag difference is great enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your contributions! Some were actually really helpful, some not so much lol; thanks anyway for taking your time to post.

So, to summarise, there isn't a 29er frame that will take a compact road crankset, or at least people don't know about it. However there are workarounds which will ALMOST achieve my desired result. 
Thanks everyone!

P.S. I'll update this post if I find a frame like that, I wouldn't bet on it coz of clearance + chainline issues